# neo4j DatabaseNotFoundError, with status "offline"

Tags: neo4j

I had a neo4j database on my personal computer(window 10). When I try to migrate this database to the server(centos7).

I use script like this to export the database:

```
neo4j-admin  dump --database=neo4j --to=<someplace>/neo4j.dump
```

I copy the dump file to server, and try to import it to neo4j on my server:

```
neo4j-admin load --from=/var/lib/neo4j/data/dumps/neo4j.dump --database=neo4j --force
```

When I start neo4j, and enter the neo4j browser, it says that

```
DatabaseNotFoundError
Database "neo4j" is unavailable, its status is "offline".
```

The version of neo4j on my computer and server are both 4.4.3.

How can I restore my database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- In the web console select the system db and run the query `show databases`
- It will show if there are any errors
- Then check the `debug.log` of neo4j for the reason
- In my case the issue was, I had used the root user `load` the dump. I had to manually change file permissions

Comment: Yes. Need to chmod both user and group. Like chown neo4j:neo4j -R /var/lib/neo4j/data/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and had to first drop the database `DROP DATABASE neo4j` then create a new database `CREATE DATABASE neo4j`.

Comment: This is really bad advice, dropping a whole database means losing all the data from that database....

Comment: Also creating is not possible in the community version.

Answer (score 0):

You're describing an issue where the browser lost connection to the database (since you stopped the database in order to reload from file). To connect anew, close the browser and open a new window (example: http://localhost:7474/browser/); this should prompt you to connect again. It is possible to reconnect an old browser window after database shutdown+start, but close+open is easier to explain.

Also, to confirm your other steps, they look fine for taking the dump and loading it. The following works for me with neo4j Community 4.4.5:

- first, stop the database:

  ```
  % ./bin/neo4j stop      
  Stopping Neo4j....... stopped.
  ```
- run `dump`, saving to a new file named "export.dat":

  ```
  % ./bin/neo4j-admin dump --database=neo4j --to=export.dat
  Selecting JVM - Version:11.0.14+8-LTS-263, Name:Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit       Server VM, Vendor:Oracle Corporation
  Done: 40 files, 334.5MiB processed.
  ```
- run `load` to put "export.dat" back to the same "neo4j" database:

  ```
  % ./bin/neo4j-admin load --from=export.dat --database=neo4j --force
  Selecting JVM - Version:11.0.14+8-LTS-263, Name:Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Vendor:Oracle Corporation
  Done: 40 files, 334.5MiB processed.
  ```
- start the database again:

  ```
  % ./bin/neo4j start      
  Directories in use:
  [...]
  Starting Neo4j.
  Started neo4j (pid:3852). It is available at http://localhost:7474
  There may be a short delay until the server is ready.
  ```